# Sliding down dropdown using css only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to sliding down a sub menu. The reference which I am following is -- https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch

But the dropdown doesn't slide. It just appears on hover.

Html code --

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="clearfix">
  <div class="nav-inner clearfix">
    <div class="menu-main-navigation-container">
      <ul id="nav" class="clearfix page">
        <li class="item">
          <a href="" class="title">Menu</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="item"><a href="" class="title">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="" class="title">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/seqc1w9f/6/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display` cannot be animated. This needs to be removed.

```
ul#nav li ul {
  display: none;
```